# Ordenar lista com Python + Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, django, for

Boa tarde galera, estou com um problema, cadastro pelo admin do django um vídeo que deverá ser enviado ao meu template, porém eu preciso que esses vídeos fiquem ordenados pelo campo `position` que tenho na minha `models.py` que eu seto no banco

***models.py***:

```js
from django.db import models

class Video(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Link Embed')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Título')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='Descrição do video')
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Estará disponível quando')
    position = models.CharField(max_length=255 ,verbose_name='Qual posição')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} {self.description} {self.start_date} - {self.url}'
```

***video-list.html***:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        {% for video in videos %}
        <div>
            <h1>
                {{video.title}}
            </h1>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{video.url}}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p>
                {{video.description}}
            </p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***views.py***:

```js
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from datetime import date
from .models import *
from .forms import *
import requests
import random

def videos_list(request):
    
    if 'lead_id' in request.session:        
        videos = Video.objects.all()
        for video in videos:
            print(video.titlle)
        return render(request, 'videos-list.html', {'videos': videos})

    return redirect('registrations:create_lead')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta colocar o campo `ordering` dentro dos metadados do modelo  - algo do tipo:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    url = ...
    ...
    position = ...
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["position"]
```

O Django faz uso da caracateristica do Python que permite que seja declarada uma classe dentro de uma classe para permitir que você coloque uma série de opções e configurações dentro de cada modelo. É importnte ter em metne que esse `Meta` não é usado como uma classe - nem deveria ser chamado de metaclasse, apesar de históricamente, no Django, ela ter começado assim - é simplesmente usado como um espaço de nome (namespace)  para declarar opções sem o risco das mesmas conflitarem com campos do seu modelo.

O ORM do Django usa o "ordering" para organizar suas queries por padrão. (Atenção que seu campo "posição" é texto, o que significa que "11" vem na frente de "2", por exemplo).

A documentação para o `ordering` e outras opções do Meta está aqui:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#ordering

Outra forma é explícitar o `order_by` na query - troque a linha:

```
    videos = Video.objects.all()
```

Por

```
    videos = Video.objects.order_by("position").all()
```

Documentação pra query:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: usei `videos = Video.objects.order_by("position").all()` para res[olver o meu problema, porém como você comentou testei trocar a posição de um video de 0 para 11 e ele ficou na frente de video posição 2 mesmo, como eu poderia resolver esse problema ? mudando o tipo do campo de charfield ?

Comment: troquei o campo de: `position = models.CharField(verbose_name='Qual posição')` para `position = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Qual posição')` e deu certo